# Why can't we provide size to the String[] args in java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

While doing a program, one question came in my mind that, we can provide size to all the array but why can't we provide the size in "String[] args" array in java.
For example"

```
public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( "Hello World" );
     }
}
```

If I will run the above program then I will not get any error but if I will try to provide size to String[] of main method then I will get compile time error.
Can you please make me clear that why this problem is coming.

Thankyou

Comment: because you have no way of knowing what parameters the user will provide. You can check the size in the method, if that is what you want.

Comment: The designers of the Java language decided that you can not force a specific size for arrays. The size is not part of the type. The type of `args` is just `String[]` and not maybe `String[3]` like in other languages. Instead, you would simply throw an exception like `if (args.length > 3) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("blabla"); }`.

Comment: "we can provide size to all the array" - not for *parameters* you can't, ever. You specify the size of an array when you create it, not when you *receive* it.

Answer (score 4):

You can only set the length of an array when **you're** the one initializing it:

```
String[] array = new String[42];
```

But when you expect an array as a parameter of a the method, like in the `main()`-method, **you're not** the one initializing the array, but the caller is.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

In this case the JVM will initialize `args` with the command line arguments. If you pass no arguments then the array will be of length `0`.